# Regular expression to select only the words surrounded by whitespaces

Tags: regex

I'm looking for a regular expression that allows me to select words surrounded by whitespaces. The obvious pattern `/\s(\w*)\s/g` does not work because end of line is considered as whitespace.

I need something like this:

> not-match **match** not-match
>
> not-match **match** not-match

Comment: The end of line *is* whitespace.

Comment: Then, try `/(?![\n\r])\s/g`.

Comment: You can use `/ (\w+) /`

Comment: Could you provide the language in which you are using this regex?  Sometimes that makes it a little clearer as to which syntax is allowed.

Comment: If it is PHP, use `/\h(\w+)\h/`. If it is .NET, use `\p{Zs}(\w+)\p{Zs}`. For JS, I guess anubhava's suggestion is the best unless you really need to use `\s`: `/(?![\r\n])\s(\w+)(?![\r\n])\s/g`.

Comment: What actually is your issue? Is it that the *interline* gets matched as well (http://www.regexr.com/3c3m7)? In which case you just need to use `+` instead of `*` (*"one or more"* instead of *"zero or more"*, http://www.regexr.com/3c3ma).

Comment: Here I read three good answers. Why are comments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\s` will match the non-printing white"space" characters `\n` and `\r` as well, yes. If you only want to match the characters that actually leave "space", you have to specify them. Also, use the zero-width lookahead and lookbehind so as not to "consume" the space for the neighboring words matches:

```
/(?<=[ \t])(\w+)(?=[ \t])/g
```

Comment: Correct, but no need to capture the word; the *entire* match is the word